# Yes, another "Package inputenc error" question

Tags: errors, packages, unicode, accents, input-encodings

I'm trying to figure out why LaTeX behaves this way.

So, I have this project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12774331/latex.zip

which is a perfectly working project, with lots of `é` and other accented letters in it. It compiles just fine.

Then I've got this one: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12774331/Thesis.zip

which gives me a "Package inputenc Error" just with some accented letters.

Really, it's driving me mad. I'm using TexPad on OS X (10.9) with the usual MaxTex distribution, leaving the default `pdfLatex` compiler for both projects. Actually, *every* options is the same across the two projects.

What could be the problem?
(sorry for posting `.zip` archives, I just can't produce a minimal working example since I don't know where the problem comes from)

Comment: Unicode offers some strange possibilities to "construct" accented characters. For instance, U+0300, "COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT" will go over the **previous** letter. This probably can't be implemented well with TeX, but I've seen a lot of texts (from Macs) containing those :-(

Comment: Yeah I just found that out. I use an US layout but live in Italy so i have to deal with accented letters quite often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In chapter one, you have inserted some strange characters. Don't know, where you got them from. They look like an other font in my TeXnicCenter. Just delete it (like the `ù` in più in my MWE) and type it again. Maybe some copy/paste issue.

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% [12pt] è la dimensione del testo
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\begin{document}    
\chapter{Modello solare standard}
\section{Introduzione}
Il Sole è una stella della sequenza principale. La fase evolutiva più stabile e duratura in cui una stella brucia l’idrogeno presente nel core attraverso una serie di reazioni nucleari. 
\end{document}
```

BTW: By deleting one package after an other and by reducing the amount of text, the error was easy to spot. Please put some effort in giving an MWE the next time.